# Прозрачность в navigationBar

Tags: java, android, material-design

Каким образом можно сделать прозрачность у Navigation Bar, как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**update:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relative_activity"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:transitionName="actionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:paddingBottom="48dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/lol"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работает на api >= 19

Тема:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
</style>
```

Теперь мы можем указывать paddingBottom для ListView вместе с android:clipToPadding="false", иначе список будет перекрываться Navigation Barом.
В обще это применительно ко всем элементам. 
Для корневых элементов активности я указываю paddingBottom с отрицательным значением = -navigationBarHeight, потом для дочерних делаю обратный отступ как в примере ниже.

Пример:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigationBarHeight"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

android:clipToPadding="false" - не обрезать элементы, выходящие за пределы размеров элемента.

**update:**

[image: Bigtiger - main menu]

Стили:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>

</style>

<dimen name="statusBarHeight">28dp</dimen>
<dimen name="statusBarHeightMinus">-28dp</dimen>
<dimen name="navigationBarHeight">72dp</dimen>
<dimen name="navigationBarHeightMinus">-72dp</dimen>
```

Разметка главной (Toolbar заменяет ActionBar)

```
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/statusBarHeightMinus"
   android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/navigationBarHeightMinus">

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/statusBarHeight" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigationBarHeight"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_main_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="ru.dvfx.bigtiger.NavigationMenuMain"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_menu_main" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Как использовать Toolbar вместо ActionBar, наследуемся (начиная c 22.1) с android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity:

```
Toolbar app_bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(app_bar);
```

В общем это на изучения с конкретным работающим примером. Ссылку на google play выложить не могу, только завершается разработка версии 1.0.

Comment: Спасибо! Но не совсем понял про отрицательное значение, и, наверное, из-за этого не совсем все получилось. Вопрос обновил. Как это исправить?